# How to make Ubuntu never use specified DNS server? (DNSLeak issues)

Tags: dns, openvpn

Im using VPN and dnsleaktest.com shows me that it discovered vpn dns and my isp dns.
I want to avoid using isp dns when using vpn.

I found I can use prepend domaine name servers in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf but all it does is give the psecified dns a priority so it doesnt disable isp dns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reject the obtained IP with

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf 
reject 192.33.137.219;
```

or leave out `domain-name-servers`

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
```

see also `man dhclient.conf`.

Comment: Why is reject ignored? The exact same ip address keeps on appearing evn though I set reject the ip address

Comment: other method is to leave out `domain-name-servers`. for more info `man dhclient.conf`